# How do I disable Real-Time Text (RTT) once enabled?

Tags: accessibility, android-11, oneplus

I have a OnePlus 8 5G UW from Verizon. At one point soon after I got the phone I was exploring features and I hit the RTT icon during a call. That turned on the on-screen keyboard so I could type rather than talk. I don't need that feature and now I cannot figure out how to turn it off. Many of my phone calls result in that RTT screen turning on and it doesn't turn off if I hold the phone to my ear, it makes it harder to get to other call features, and the disconnect button is located such that I hit it with my cheek and lose the call.

I've looked in the settings for Real-Time Text (RTT). It shows as "on" in the top level menu and the only options for changing it are:

- RTT Operation Mode

  - Visible during calls [checked]
  - Always visible (Manual)
  - Always visible (Automatic)

Does not seem to matter which of those I pick, it will still show up for many calls. There is no "Off" option and if I select "Visible during calls" it does not uncheck the option. When I make a call I don't get the original screen with the easy access to call features, like the keypad and the RTT mode, so I can't try to toggle it off.

Any idea how to turn this off or disable it entirely?

[Update] I've switched it to manual mode. Now every single phone call it asks me if I want an RTT call or a voice call. I pick voice and I get the regular call screen. Annoying every time I make a phone call but it seems that you can't force this feature off once it's turned on.

Comment: https://ostoday.org/android/how-do-i-turn-off-rtt-on-android.html

Comment: @Robert, that didn't work. So far I have to live with this. Stupid phone.